# I tried to upload a Django project in Heroku and end up with +4000 pending changes in source control

Tags: python, django, heroku

The other day I was doing a guided project and the final step was to upload the project in Heroku and everything worked. Now, I want to do the same thing again, and I followed the same steps, but it's now not working .

[image]

Somehow following the commands I ended up with this. The questions are:

1. How can I go back or start again from scratch? The Heroku website guide is so confusing
2. Can someone tell me the easiest steps to upload the project in Heroku? (I'm using Python)
3. Also does the project has to be upload in Github properly in order to upload in Heroku?

Comment: what do you mean by 'start again from scratch,' can't you just make a new project?

Comment: About those +4000 files I think I did something wrong, I tried different ways to upload to heroku and nothing works

Comment: You added your virtualenv ('./venv') folder to your repository. Probably through `git add .` either in a hook or manually. You need to add that folder to `.gitignore`.

Comment: But I have a .gitignore file in the folder